# How is Inverse Super Floater built?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, floating-rate

I am pretty new to fixed income and came across to a product called Inverse Super Floater.
I am wondering, what are the components of this product assuming issue price of 100 (redemption amount of 100 at maturity) and coupon with the payoff of Max (0, [1.40% -2 x LIBOR]) paid semi-annually.

Comment: What do you mean by components?

Comment: Sorry for maybe being a bit unclear. Rephrasing my question: With what instruments could one replicate the mentioned payoff of the product.